# Opening URL in youtube app does not work the first time

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, uiapplication

In my app, I open up a youtube video like such:

```
 NSURL *youtubeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:youtubeURL];
```

When I do this and I have the youtube app installed, it will open up youtube, but not load the video. It will just go to the youtube homepage. But if I do it again, it will load video.

I have trouble reproducing the problem, but has anyone seen this? It usually happens after not using the youtube app for a while.

Comment: What are the values of 'sharedApplication' and 'url'?

Comment: url is a a youtube video url. Checking on sharedApplication

Comment: sharedAppliaiton is just http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIApplication/sharedApplication

Comment: Where are u calling this?  Is it after you click on a button?

Comment: yes, in a method called by a button

Comment: If you try different youtube links do you see the same issue?  Is this video is allowed to be played on mobile device.  I think i seen this issue clicking on the link from messages.  The link just took me to the youtube homepage in the youtube app

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, but it has happened many times. I can't figure out what causes it!